# Email all output from Powershell script

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell script that loops through a number of files and writes the file information to the console.  What gets output to the screen is exactly what I need to send via an email.

The email part was easy, but I can't figure out how to capture what gets sent to the screen and send it in the body.  Here is the relevant code.  Only the first iteration gets stored in the $emailbody variable.

**EDITED EXAMPLE:**

```
$backupLocations = #List of paths#

$emailBody=""
$currentFile = "nothing"
foreach ($loc in $backupLocations) {
    $files = get-childitem "$loc\\*" -recurse -include *.bak    
    foreach ($file in $files) {
        if (test-path $file) {
            $prop = Get-ItemProperty -Path "$file"
            Write-Output $prop | tee-Object -variable $currentFile
            $emailBody += $currentFile
        }
    }     
} 

# Code to send $emailBody in an email.  That is working fine.#
```

What I see on screen is pages worth of file information such as this:

```
    Directory: \\directory\directory\directory\myfolder

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                                                          
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                                                          
-a---         5/10/2011  10:00 PM    1986048 file.bak
```

Admittedly I have not RTFM and have basically hacked my way through Powershell to this point, so please forgive me if the answer is an obvious one.

Comment: Some basic question: is that a function? or just a part of your script? What are you checking with `if($file)`?

Comment: @empo, thanks, I've added the rest of the code.  I was just testing if the $file exists, which I see is better done with the `test-path` commandlet

Comment: @Ken Pespisa: Are you ok then or still in trouble?

Comment: @Ken Pespisa edit the output line to `Write-Output $prop | tee-Object -variable currentFile` There should be no `$` for currentFile.

Comment: @Ken Pespisa - see my updated answer on simplifying the script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't you be trying something like this:

```
$emailBody=""
foreach ($file in $files) {
    if ($file) {
        $prop = Get-ItemProperty -Path "$file"
        Write-Output $prop | tee-Object -Variable currentFile
        $emailBody += $currentFile
    }        
}
```

There are better ways to do what you are doing though. So if you can give details on what $files is and whether you really want to output to console as well etc. we can look at a better script.

**After your update:**

Wouldn't something like below work for you:

```
$files = gci "$loc\\*" -recurse -include *.bak
Write-Host $files
$emailBody = $files | ft
```

I don't think anything else is needed! Like `test-path` - why? you are doing a gci, of course it exists!

Comment: That resolves the problem of having overwritten the `$emailBody` isn't? But `write-output` for each file is not so nice, it would print the header for each one, am I right?

Comment: Yes, I was just suggesting for now. Based on what $files is he should probably pipe that. Or directly use `gci` or something.

Comment: @manojlds, I tried your code but needed to put a value into $currentFile because the Tee-Object commandlet was reporting "Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Variable' because it is null."  I set the variable equal to the word "nothing" and the script ran.  But the email report just showed the word "nothing" repeated 100+ times (i.e. once for each file found)

Comment: @Ken Pespisa - oops, there is a silly mistake in that. See my updated answer. That part should be `tee-Object -Variable currentFile
` notice no `$`

Comment: @Ken Pespisa - see my updated answer. Would that script work for you?

Comment: @Ken Pespisa: I'm with @manojlds, you do not need `testpath` at all.

Comment: @Ken Pespisa: you also do not need `get-itemproperty` unless you want select a subset of them. What you can obviously do with `format-table`

Comment: Losing the $ did the trick!  I'm going to try the other ideas too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Each iteration your `$emailBody` is overwritten. Moreover, the header of your properties will be printed for each file I think. I would try:

```
$props = @()
$files | %  {
    $prop = Get-ItemProperty -Path "$file"
    $props += $prop
}
$emailbody = $props | format-table -auto
```